# sub-property write commit withing store actions using vuex-pathify make.mutations

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Here is how my store looks like:

```
const state = {
    user: {
        profile: {
            phoneNumber: '',
        }
    }
}

const mutations = make.mutations(state)

const actions = {
    submitPhoneNumber({commit}, phone_number) {
        // blah blah
        commit('SET_USER@profile.phoneNumber', phone_number);
    }
}
```

But no such mutation can be found.
Maybe I could import store.js within store.js and use the `set` helper but I believe things can get pretty creepy specially because of the (In my opinion poor) design decision that the library creator has made to combine commit and dispatch (I believe being explicit would have been much better here)

Comment: You have to show what `make.mutations()` does.

Comment: @acdcjunior https://davestewart.github.io/vuex-pathify/#/api/store?id=make-mutations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pathify author here.

You can't commit a mutation with sub-property syntax using Vuex mutations, because Vuex will treat it as a string.

You are correct that you would need to use `store.set()` to do this.

You can be explicit with commits and dispatches by appending a `!` to the call. This is called "direct syntax":

- https://davestewart.github.io/vuex-pathify/#/api/paths?id=direct-syntax

To commit directly using the sub-property syntax, use the `Payload` class:

- https://github.com/davestewart/vuex-pathify/blob/master/src/classes/Payload.js
- https://davestewart.github.io/vuex-pathify/#/api/properties?id=payload-class

Something like this should work:

```
import { Payload } from 'vuex-pathify'
commit('SET_USER', new Payload('SET_USER', @profile.phoneNumber', phone_number);
```

Looks like I haven't documented this, so I have a made a ticket here:

- https://github.com/davestewart/vuex-pathify/issues/80

It's using a commit from a component, but should work just the same.

People have asked before if it would be possible to use Pathify-style commits in actions and I said it wasn't, but I've just thought of something that might make it possible.

Follow this feature request for more info:

- https://github.com/davestewart/vuex-pathify/issues/79

Comment: thanks for explanation, very helpful. 
But shouldn't it be `'@profile/phoneNumber'`? as Pathify's syntax assumes obj/prop not obj.prop

Comment: @BennyK `/` identify from modules to top-level properties (Vuex's default) then `@` identifies the sub-property barrier and `.` any sub-properties below that. There are historical reasons for doing that, before you ask why not `foo/bar.baz` !

Comment: weird, i've got this working fine in my project: `commit('uiStore/usersResponses', new Payload('uiStore/usersResponses', '@502/en', `${error.response}: ${error.error_message}`), { root: true })`

Comment: since we're talking, can you please explain why inside a component both getters work:

`myTabs: get('uiStore/menuItems@myTabs'),`

 `myTabs: get('uiStore/menuItems.myTabs'),`


I noticed by accident, and trying to understand whether using `.` instead of `@` is a bad practice here.

Comment: Hey, sorry for late reply. The resolver code is something I wanted to review at some point, and did get into a while ago, but you know... life. It's very possible that I just didn't code it carefully enough. If I was smart, I would have written tests! You can take a look here if you are curious: https://github.com/davestewart/vuex-pathify/blob/master/src/services/resolver.js#L104